# What the difference between print server and shared printer

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2019, printing, shared-printers

i planning to add new print service, but i don't know add a new role ( print server )  or just  shared printer(smb) will better?

i planning shared to windows and Mac

Comment: it depends on your own network. usually a print server keeps the driver and the client doesn't need them or if they will be delivered on demand. A shared printer csn be used from anyone but needs a direct installation on any device mostly with administrator rights. Moreover over, share a printer is a bad choice imho, as it does not allow to print while unavailable, but with the print role and print directly it might be possible